# python packaging for relative imports

Tags: python, python-import

First off all: I'm sorry, I know there has been lots of question about relative imports, but I just didn't find a solution. If possible I would like to use the following directory layout:

```
myClass/
    __init__.py
    test/
        demo.py
        benchmark.py
        specs.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        myClass.py
```

Now my questions are:

- How do the test files from within the package properly import myClass.py?
- How would you import the package from outside, assuming you take myClass as submodule in libs/myClass or include/myClass?

So far I couldn't find an elegant solution for this. From what I understand [Guido's Decision](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) it should be possible to do `from ..src import myClass` but this will error:

`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Which looks as it doesn't treat myClass as packages. [Reading the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages;

It seems I'm missing something that specifies where the scripts of the package are, should I use .pth ?

Comment: @Brent Newey, yes you are right, relative imports seems to be an ongoing topic and after reading quite a few answers I still felt the urge to specifically describe my situation. After showing this q, on the #python IRC channel quite a few people recommended to use flat directory structure: "A lot of people resist the way Python wants to use directories and files for semantic namespace information. It's best just to give in and do what Python wants." http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html

Comment: Could anyone provide a link to some real-world packages, with exemplary directory layout, or following some conventions? (ideally on github)

Comment: Is there `__init__.py` in the `test` directory? `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` might be related to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803292/initialize-project-layout-in-python http://docs.python.org/distutils/examples.html

Comment: Reading the official documentation helped me a lot!
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Answer (score 42):

> `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Means you attempt to use relative import in the module which is not package. Its problem with the file which has this `from ... import` statement, and not the file which you are trying to import.

So if you are doing relative imports in your tests, for example, you should make your tests to be part of your package. This means

1. Adding `__init__.py` to test/
2. Running them from some outside script, like nosetests

If you run something as `python myClass/test/demo.py`, relative imports will not work too since you are running demo module not as package. Relative imports require that the module which uses them is being imported itself either as package module, `from myClass.test.demo import blabla`, or with relative import.

Answer (score 28):

After hours of searching last night I found the answer to relative imports in python!! Or an easy solution at the very least. The best way to fix this is to have the modules called from another module. So say you want `demo.py` to import `myClass.py`. In the `myClass` folder at the root of the sub-packages they need to have a file that calls the other two. From what I gather the working directory is always considered `__main__` so if you test the import from `demo.py` with the `demo.py` script, you will receive that error. To illustrate:

Folder hierarchy:

```
myClass/
    main.py #arbitrary name, can be anything
    test/
        __init__.py
        demo.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        myClass.py
```

myClass.py:

```
def randomMaths(x):
    a = x * 2
    y = x * a
    return y
```

demo.py:

```
from ..src import myClass

def printer():
    print(myClass.randomMaths(42))
```

main.py:

```
import test.demo

demo.printer()
```

If you run `demo.py` in the interpreter, you will generate an error, but running `main.py` will not. It's a little convoluted, but it works :D

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and I only got the above code to work by doing three things. First, at the level where main.py is, I added a `__init__.py`. Second, I changed demo.printer() to `test.demo.printer()`. Third, I changed directory above the main.py and ran `python -m myClass.main`. Otherwise, this was a very helpful answer to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Intra-package-references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) describes how to `myClass` from `test/*`. To import the package from outside, you should add its path to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before running the importer application, or to `sys.path` list in the code before importing it.

Why `from ..src import myClass` fails: probably, `src` is not a python package, you cannot import from there. You should add it to python path as described above.

Comment: Relative imports are done all the time.  Many packages have smaller sub packages with in them and rely on relative imports.  the OP is not asking how to reference external packages.  He is asking how to reference another sub package within a package.