# Python : how to import module in other module

Tags: python, import, packaging

I have following directory structure

```
outdir
     |--lib
            |--- __init__.py
            |--- abc.py
     |--indir
            |--- __init__.py
            |---- import_abc.py
```

How to import `lib` in `import_abc.py`?

when i try to import lib in import_abc.py

I get following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_abc.py", line 1, in <module>
  import lib
  ImportError: No module named lib
```

Comment: This link might help you.
http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: Have a look at this thread on relative imports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports-again-sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `__init__.py` file in `outdir` and then do:

```
#import_abc.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/monty/py')   #path to directory that contains outdir
from outdir.lib import abc
```

Comment: Thanks! seems like it worked.. but i had to append path upto outdir

Comment: @NikhilRupanawar glad that helped, you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

Take a minute to look at what you're trying to achieve: you want to import the
 module abc.py which is a part of the package lib, so in order to import it correctly you need to specify in which package it is:

```
from lib import abc
```

or

```
import lib.abc as my_import
```

On a side note, have a look at [the Python Tutorial chapter on modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Given what @Noelkd commented, I forgot to tell you about PYTHONPATH which is an environment variable that contains the folder where Python will look for the module (like the Java CLASSPATH). You need to put your root folder inside the PYTHONPATH to avoid doing some fiddling with sys.path.append.

In Bash:

```
export PYTHONPATH=<abs. path to outdir>
```

For example, I've put outdir in my Desktop:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/Desktop/outdir
```

And the import works like a charm.

You can find some great explanations of the import mechanism and PYTHONPATH in [this blog post](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath).

N.B.: If you're using an IDE (PyDev for example), generally it will set up the PYTHONPATH automatically for each project. But if you want to do it all by yourself, you will need to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: blog post link no longer working it seems?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced similar problem. There are 2 ways of importing modules generally. One is absolute path, the other one is relative path.

For absolute path, python uses `sys.path` to resolve the path, as suggested by above answers. But personally I don't like manipulate `sys.path`.

For relative path, python uses `__name__` resolve the path. Say an module has `__name__` as `package1.package2.module3` and module3 imports module in upper package using `from ..packge3 import module4`. Python will combine them to get `package1.packge3.module4`. Details have been illustrated in [this](http://livoras.com/post/7) post.

My solution is adding an `/outside` dir as the parent dir of `/outdir` and make `outdir` as a package by adding `__init__.py` under `/outdir`.

Then you can add `from ..lib.abc import cls` in `import_abc.py` file. The relative path should work

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../lib')
import abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set parent `outdir` directory as module adding a `__init__.py` to it too:

```
outdir
     |-- __init__.py
     |-- lib
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- abc.py
     |-- indir
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- import_abc.py
```

Then in `import_abc.py` you will be able to import `lib` if adding `outdir`'s path:

```
#In import_abc.py

import sys
sys.path.append('../outdir')
import lib.abc
```