# Python relative import fails in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am defining a new Python pipeline for Maya 2012 and I am having difficulty setting up package properly.

I have:

```
Prod
    __init__.py
        PackA
            __init__.py
            PAMod1.py

        PackB
            __init__.py
            PBMod2.py

PAMod1
    def a():pass

PAMod2
    def b():pass
```

How do I call `PAMod1.b` in `PAMod2.b`?

How do I call module with the whole name `Prod.PackA.PAMod1.a()` inside `PAMod2.b`?

Comment: Which Python Version - it __does__ make a difference?

Comment: @theodox all versions of Maya, up till 2013, use 2.6

Answer (score 2):

as long as *Prod* is on the python path, you can do this - the safest way, using absolute paths

```
# in PAMod2.py

import Prod.PackA.PAMod1

Prod.PackA.PAMod1.Function()
```

or (still safe, easier to type):

```
# in PAMod2.py

import Prod.PackA.PAMod1 as Mod1 

Mod1.Function()
```

You can reference a sibling package as well.  This only works inside a module - you can'd do it interactively ( ie, from the maya script editor) . It's also a going to break if eather PackA or PackB moves

```
# in PAMod2.py

from .. import PAMod1

PAMod1.Function()
```

The python docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)  and this is a [good SO question on the same (common) topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports-again-sorry)

Comment: for some reason, if I try the above Maya throws an error: No module named PackA.PAMod1

Comment: it happens when I try to import Prod.PackA.PAMod1 into __init__.py . Do you have any idea what may be the problem?