# Python/Django TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-extensions

After years of writing in C and C++, I feel a bit of a dunce when it comes to python and django. I can't seem to get something simple to work. I concede that the error has been discussed in a number of posts.

I started going through some django tutorials so I have run 'django-admin startproject mysite' which has created a 'mysite' folder.

I've installed django_extensions so now I'm trying to use its 'runscript'. I have a more complex script that I want to run later but for now, I'm trying to invoke a simple user script which I found online via this mechanism i.e.

```
mysimplescript.py:

def run(*script_args):
print script_args
```

It is located in a 'scripts' folder so my structure is as follows, where the outer mysite/ root directory is just a container for my project:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    scripts
        __init__.py
        mysimplescript.py
```

When I run the script as follows, I get the relative imports error.

```
python manage.py runscript .scripts.mysimplescript.py --script-args  
Testing 123

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core 
/management/base.py:265:  RemovedInDjango110Warning: 
OptionParser usage for Django management commands is deprecated, use 
ArgumentParser instead

RemovedInDjango110Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core  
/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core 
/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 63, in   
run_from_argv
super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core 
/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 75, in execute
super(EmailNotificationCommand, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/core 
/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 57, in inner
ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 163, in handle
modules = find_modules_for_script(script)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 146, in  
find_modules_for_script
mod = my_import(nn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ 
django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 99, in my_import
importlib.import_module(mod)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 30, in import_module
raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument
```

If I include the debug, then I can see the following @ runscript.py #99:
    Check for .scripts.mysimplescript.scripts.py

Having initially run some django tutorials, the following have been set:

```
./mysite/wsgi.py:os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",  
"mysite.settings")
./manage.py:    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 
"mysite.settings")
./mysite/settings.py:ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

Some of the discussions on the topic e.g. [1]:[python packaging for relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports) and [2]:[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) suggest adding a main.py in the outer mysite/ directory.

In essence, though, I still want to invoke the script via django-extensions using:

```
python manage.py runscript  <some_script>
```

Just a further point. If I drop the '.' preceding the folder i.e.

```
python manage.py runscript scripts.mysimplescript.py --script-args Testing 
123
```

then I get the following error:

```
No (valid) module for script 'scripts.mysimplescript.py' found
```

yet a 'mysimplescript.pyc' is generated.

Can someone help me please?  How can I get python to recognize the package? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py runscript mysimplescript`? That seems equivalent to the example [in the docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html#usage) where you run `python manage.py runscript delete_all_polls` to run `scripts/delete_all_polls.py`.

Comment: Alasdair, yes, I have.   

    python manage.py runscript mysimplescript.py --script-args Testing     123      I get the same error:  Check for mysimplescript.py
No (valid) module for script 'mysimplescript.py' found

Comment: Try `mysimplescript` with no `.py`.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks a million!!  Check for scripts.mysimplescript
('Testing', '123')

Comment: check in python >>> from mysite import settings. also >>> from mysite import scripts. What do you get?

Answer (score 2):

The example [in the docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html#usage) is to save the script as `scripts/delete_all_questions.py`, and then run it with

```
python manage.py runscript delete_all_questions
```

In your case, your script is `scripts/mysimplescript.py`, so you run it with

```
python manage.py runscript mysimplescript --script-args Testing 123
```

Note that you use the module name `mysimplescript`, so you shouldn't include `.py`. The django_extensions app assumes that scripts are in a `scripts` directory, so don't include that either.

Comment: Alasdair, as it turns out, I had previously created the file 'delete_all_polls.py' in the same 'scripts/' folder containing 'mysimplescript.py', so why do I get the 'No (valid) module for script 'delete_all_polls' found' error when running 'python manage.py runscript delete_all_polls'?  The interesting thing is that if you temporarily remove the 'from..import' at the top, the module is recognized but the 'Poll' object is obviously not recognized.

Comment: File "/usr/tester/SwFact/isg_cid-system_test_current/my_site/scripts/delete_all_polls.py", line 7, in run
    all_polls = Poll.objects.all()
NameError: global name 'Poll' is not defined

Comment: Unless you have an app `Polls` with a model `Poll` then I would expect that import to fail. That example from the docs isn't ideal - for Django 1.8+, you would have `from polls.models import Question` if you were following the tutorial. For earlier versions of the tutorial, the app would be lower case i.e. `from polls.models import Poll`. If you don't import or define `Poll`, then the `NameError` isn't surprising either.

Comment: The example in the [runscript docs](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html) has now been updated so that it matches the tutorial for Django 1.8+ more closely.

Comment: Thanks, Alasdair. I found this django-extensions pdf document which appears to have been uploaded recently, containing the same updated example.  [2] (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-extensions/latest/django-extensions.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports can run only from a python package. The directory you use the relative import shoul:
1. Contain an **init**.py file
2. Available to the PYTHONPATH (declared as a path, or sub-directory of another directory which has **init**.py and is on the path)

In other words, relative path will not work in a script unless you call the entire package:

```
$ python -m manage.py runscript mystie.scripts.mysimplescript
```

Comment: It seems that enough is 1 *or* 2. A link to the source in Python docs would be perfect. In your example the path is not relative (as I understand, that must begin with a dot?). However I used that and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This will work..

```
python manage.py runscript mysimplescript --script-args Testing 
123
```