# 3 level chained python import is failing

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following folder structure across 3 levels: folder1 contains folder1_1 which again contains folder1_1_1. Now we have a .py file in each folder (besides the '**init**.py' which is apparently needed, and sorry I don't know how to put those 2 lines before and after).

```
folder1  
L __init__.py  
L file1.py  
L folder1_1  
  L __init__.py  
  L file1_1.py  
  L folder1_1_1  
    L __init__.py  
    L file1_1_1.py
```

File contents
file1.py

```
from folder1_1.file1_1 import Test1_1 as lvl2
class Test1:
    randomnumber = 1
    sum = randomnumber  + lvl2.sum
    print (sum)
```

file1_1.py

```
from folder1_1_1.file1_1_1 import Test1_1_1 as lvl3
class Test1_1:
    somenumber = 1
    sum = somenumber + lvl3.someothernumber
    print (sum)
```

file1_1_1.py

```
class Test1_1_1:
    someothernumber = 1
```

So each file imports from the directly lower folder. One step works:
When I run file1_1.py the import from file1_1_1 works fine, and it produces the desired result (2)

But the '2 level' import in file1 fails:

```
  File "c:\Users\DSCO\Documents\folder1\folder1_1\file1_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder1_1_1.file1_1_1 import Test1_1_1 as lvl3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1_1_1'
```

How can I import in this manner? Or do I need to rearrange my folders? In the actual code this structure is quite involved with file1_1 having many import statements pointing to file1_1_1 which is actually many files. Thats why the separate subfolder (folder1_1_1)
I checked multiple S.O. issues but they are all somewhat different in my estimation.

Comment: thanks Pranav, I could not figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 366](https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/) may be of interest here, but you don't need the `-m` flag in this case. In your case, the only difference is the import within folder1_1/file1_1.py. I import starting from the entry **name** where it was run, so `folder1_1` is included. You can also see more information in these answers:

- [How to do relative imports in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852/2081835)
- [python packaging for relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713254/2081835)

The closest to your example that works is:

### file tree

```
➜ tree
.
├── file1.py
└── folder1_1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── file1_1.py
    └── folder1_1_1
        ├── __init__.py
        └── file1_1_1.py
```

### file1.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from folder1_1.file1_1 import Test1_1 as lvl2


class Test1:
    randomnumber = 1
    sum = randomnumber + lvl2.sum
    print(sum)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Test1()
```

### folder1_1/file1_1.py

```py
from folder1_1.folder1_1_1.file1_1_1 import Test1_1_1 as lvl3


class Test1_1:
    somenumber = 1
    sum = somenumber + lvl3.someothernumber
    print(sum)
```

### folder1_1/folder1_1_1/file1_1_1.py

```py
class Test1_1_1:
    someothernumber = 1
    print(someothernumber)
```

Now if you run from the top folder:

```
./file1.py
```

It yields the output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: So I guess the basic rule is that the import statements in modules that themselves are imported (e.g. file1_1) need to modify their own import statements as if called from the main module, making them impossible to run at their own level. My file1_1.py ran by itself, now no more. But that's ok, works!

Comment: Yes essentially. At least that is the expected pattern. But there are many different ways to make things work. You can use relative imports, or you can use the `sys` module to modify the python path on the fly as you see fit.