# Ruby Packaging Ecosystem As Python Terminolgies

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, comparison, packaging

I have some experience with Ruby, but it’s less than my Python experience. I've packaged and published several Python packages, but there’s only one Ruby package I've published. I want to learn rapidly about Ruby packaging ecosystem by comparing to Python.

- I believe that there’s the tool equivalent to virtualenv in Ruby, but I don’t know what is that yet. What are the roles of RVM and Bundler?
- When I write a Python package, I usually use `setup.py develop` command — it resolves the dependencies but is not installed to site-packages. What is the equivalent thing in Ruby?
- What is the preferred way to make a directory layout structure of Ruby packages?
- Gem package naming rule. Is Gem name case sensitive? Should it be the same as the contained Ruby module's name?
- Any other points I missed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RVM is similar to virtualenv also checkout rbenv (perhaps more like virtualenv)

Bundler is for packaging dependencies for development and deployment, it works like `setup.py` and pip (I haven't used pip, it seems to have some features of rubygems and Bundler)

Bundler's `Gemfile` is similar to pip's requirement file

Bundler will install dependencies in your development directory, and package them for deployment.

Directory layouts tend to look like this:

```
/ -
  lib - classes / modules etc.
  bin - executables things you want on $PATH
  test - unit tests
```

[Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) is a good tool for setting up, maintaining and releasing gems.

EDIT:

Here are some other resources:

Some links on Ruby layout:

- [Directory layout for pure Ruby project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362/directory-layout-for-pure-ruby-project)
- [Ideal ruby project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614309/ideal-ruby-project-structure)
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213637

Some for Python:

- [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)
- [Initialize project layout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803292/initialize-project-layout-in-python)

Here's one making a comparison of tools:

- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2513005

Comment: So where does rubygems come into play?  Does it download code from a package repository and unpack it much like pip and easy_install are used for?

Comment: yes, rubygems provides the `gem` command for installing and managing ruby "gems" or packages.